# EAK and tastypie adapter integration

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, tastypie, ember-app-kit

What is the best approach to use EAK and [ember-data-tastypie-adapter](https://github.com/escalant3/ember-data-tastypie-adapter)?

I am currently trying the following:

- Django running on `localhost:7000`
- EAK running on `localhost:8000`
- Added ember-data-tastypie-adapter to `bower.json`
- Added both JS files to `index.html`

  ```
  <script src="/vendor/ember-data-tastypie-adapter/packages/ember-data-tastypie-adapter/lib/tastypie_adapter.js"></script>
  <script src="/vendor/ember-data-tastypie-adapter/packages/ember-data-tastypie-adapter/lib/tastypie_serializer.js"></script>
  ```
- Created everything needed on Django side

I figured that I had to create `serializers/application.js` and put in it:

```
export default DS.DjangoTastypieSerializer.extend();
```

Also `adapters/application.js` needed adjustments:

```
export default DS.DjangoTastypieAdapter.extend({
    serverDomain: 'http://localhost:7000',
});
```

Requests go to Django and responses are sent. 
However in EAK this gives `"Sorry, something went wrong"` message without any further information (empty error message box). No errors in console either.

If I remove `serializers/application.js` I get similar message, in this case with information about the error:

```
Assertion Failed: Nested controllers need be referenced as [/django/tastypie],
instead of [_djangoTastypie].
Refer documentation: http://iamstef.net/ember-app-kit/guides/naming-conventions.html
```

Do I have to define `defaultSerializer` in `adapters/application.js`? If so, what is it, `/django/tastypie` or something else?

What am I missing to integrate ember-data-tastypie-adapter in EAK? Trouble is, I have not seen any example where EAK and tastypie would be working together.

Of course this two local server system is development environment. Production is planned like [here](https://github.com/escalant3/django-ember-example), both API and JS is served by one Django instance.

**UPDATE:**
Creating deployment code by `grunt dist` and serving it using Django works.

I suspect that problem lies with different JSON origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, that EAK has API proxy option.

Updated `package.json` to my API settings:

```
"proxyURL": "http://localhost:7000",
"proxyPath": "/api/v1",
```

Removed custom settings from `adapters/application.js`.

Now running `grunt server:proxy` gets data from Django. And ember.js app works without errors, not being same origin was most likely the problem.